# Drawing on overlay window of X11 ignored by gdm/metacity

Tags: c++, c, x11, cairo, composite

I am trying to build a smaller application that draws on top of all windows shown by the X11/x-server using cairo.

I found some interesting starting points out there and got a small piece of code running, which simple draws a red rectangle.
On an older Ubuntu installation in runs as expected and draws the rectangle. It also refreshs the drawing on each event, which is also the expected behaviour.
Using my Gentoo Linux installation with Gnome 3.12 (default gdm running as window manager) the program also runs, but does not seem to draw anything.
I debugged on it for a while and got no real differences between the Ubuntu and the Gnome run - except of that on Ubuntu the rectangle is shown...

Am I missing something?

**Starting the executable from a plain x11 environment using `startx` and the entry `exec test7` in ~/.xinitrc gives the expected result as well. So this all might be about the gnome window manager (is it gdm using metacity?)**

---

Here is my (small) sample code (test7.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xcomposite.h>
#include <X11/extensions/Xfixes.h>
#include <X11/extensions/shape.h>

#include <cairo/cairo.h>
#include <cairo/cairo-xlib.h>

Display *dpy;
Window overlay;

void allow_input_passthrough(Window w)
{
    XserverRegion region = XFixesCreateRegion (dpy, NULL, 0);
    XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(dpy, w, ShapeBounding, 0, 0, 0);
    XFixesSetWindowShapeRegion(dpy, w, ShapeInput, 0, 0, region);
    XFixesDestroyRegion(dpy, region);
}


int main()
{
    Window root;
    int screen, width, height;

    dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, screen);
    //root = DefaultRootWindow (dpy);

    XCompositeRedirectSubwindows(dpy, root, CompositeRedirectAutomatic);
    XSelectInput(dpy, root, SubstructureNotifyMask);

    overlay = XCompositeGetOverlayWindow(dpy, root);
    allow_input_passthrough(overlay);

    width = DisplayWidth(dpy, screen);
    height = DisplayHeight(dpy, screen);

    cairo_surface_t *surf = cairo_xlib_surface_create(dpy, overlay,
                            DefaultVisual(dpy, screen),
                            width, height);
    cairo_t *cr = cairo_create(surf);
    XSelectInput(dpy, overlay, ExposureMask);

    XEvent ev;
    for (;;) {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        printf("XNextEvent()\n");

        cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        cairo_rectangle(cr, 100.0, 100.0, 200.0, 200.0);
        cairo_fill(cr);
    }

    cairo_destroy(cr);
    cairo_surface_destroy(surf);
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles with gcc (or clang) using the command:

```
gcc test7.c -o test7 -O0 -g3 -lXfixes -lXcomposite -lcairo -lX11
```

As always: Many thanks in advance!

Sebsatian

Comment: I should add that, starting the executable in a plain x environment (via .xinitrc and startx) gives the expected result. So it might have sth. to do with gdm. I updated the thread accordingly.

Comment: Print out the coordinates, are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: Which coordinates do you mean? The width/height values? They match my screen resolution.

Comment: Yes. Also on my machine I don't seem to get a transparent window, but only a window painted with a static copy of the display content. I.e. I don't see screen updates that happen beneath.

Comment: Can you confirm, that it is working without a window manager on plain x?

Comment: It works the same way it works with a WM, i.e. no real transparency.

Comment: Oh boy I feel stupid. It works the way it works for me because I don't normally run a compositing WM. When I switch on compositing, it stops showing the rectangle, just as in your case.

Comment: Are you sure it refreshes for you with no WM?

Comment: no, but I think the main problem is, that it is not shown at all running gdm/metacity. Isn't it?

Comment: When a compositor runs it uses the overlay window itself, so you probably should not. Either open your own transparent window and keep it above others (_NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE); or use an overlay visual (not available on all hardware).